# service undefined jasmine test

Tags: angular, jasmine

testing a component that needs to subscribe to a service, but the jasmine test always fails

I log the service to the console and use `expect(contactService).toBeDefined()` which returns success

But as soon as I subscribe it returns undefined

spec:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact.component';
import { DivPositionsService } from '../../../services/div-positions.service';
import { ContactService } from '../../../services/contact.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { Email } from '../../../models/email.model';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '../../../../../node_modules/@angular/common/http/testing';
describe('ContactComponent', () => {
  let component: ContactComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ContactComponent>;
  let contactService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ContactComponent ],
      imports:[
        FormsModule, 
        ReactiveFormsModule, 
        HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers:[
        {
          provide: ContactService,
          useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('contactService', ['sendMail'])
        },
        {
        provide: DivPositionsService,
        useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('divPositionsService', ['updateObj'])
      }],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContactComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    contactService = TestBed.get(ContactService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should create form ngOnInit', () => {
    component.ngOnInit()
    expect(component.contactForm).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('should submit values from form', () => {
    const successMsg = {sucess: true, msg: 'sent'}
    const contact:Email = {
    name:'Test name',
    email: 'Test email',
    message: 'Test message',
    phone: 'Test phone'
    }
    console.log(contactService)
    expect(contactService).toBeDefined()
    contactService.sendMail(contact)
    .subscribe(results => {
      // expect(results).toBeDefined();
      //has to be what is returned by the function
      console.log(results)
      expect(results).toEqual(successMsg);


    });
    console.log(contactService)
  });

});
```

Comment: Why do you think contactService.sendMail() should return an Observable? contactService is a spy object, and you never told the spy sendMail function what it should do: https://jasmine.github.io/2.9/introduction#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.returnValue%3C/code%3E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before your call to `contactService.sendMail(contact),` you should *mock* the return value of `sendMail`, something like this.

```
contactService.sendMail.and.returnValue(Observable.of(successMsg));
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

First, you spy on the `contactService`, which following the code you provide, not be defined in anywhere.
And you should define your `contactSevice` before the `compileComponents()` function being executed.

so you should doing something like this.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ ContactComponent ],
  imports:[
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule, 
    HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
  providers:[
    ...,
    {
    provide: ContactService,
    useValue: class {
      sendMail: () => of({//what ever object you want to return here});
    }
  }],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
.compileComponents();
```

But the approach above make your mock service function called and you can't actually spy on it
If you need to spy on that and do whatever you want with mock service

You could implement a mock class like this:

```
class MockContactService {
  sendMail() {
    return of({});
  }
}

let mockContactService;

beforeEach(()=> {
  mockContactService = new MockContactService();
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     ...,
     providers:[
       {
         provide: ContactService,
         useValue: mockContactService,
     }],...
  })
  .compileComponents();

  it('what ever', () => {
    spyOn(mockContactService, 'sendMail');
  })
})
```

Comment: Why before? What does this compileComponents do?